# How to Transition From Employee to Employer?

Tags: financial-literacy, employment, small-business

I know Making the transition from employee to employer requires `financial stability, a good business plan, self-confidence and a lot of discipline`.

But i am looking for some instructions/tips from experts who made their way from employee to employer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having been both I see the pros and cons

Employers:

- Need a macro view.  Don't worry about the details that is why you hired people
- Need to get used to paper work
- Need to be hard nosed; be ready to fire or remove employees
- Need to be focused on the customer, not the product the customer gets
- Need to be focused on keeping employees happy

I personally hated all the paperwork.  Government forms, legal protection, insurance, taxes, payroll, accounting, year ends, bank accounts, inventory tracking, expenses.

The best bosses don't worry about the product, they worry about maintaining an environment that is good for the product.  Good employees who are happy will make good products that you can sell to customers who are happy with your company.

I personally went back to employee because I wanted to go home at night and forget about work.  Employers cannot do that.

Comment: Excellent answer, paints a realistic perspective.